# PyTorch load_state_dict() does not load precise value

Tags: pytorch, precision

For simplicity say I want to set all params of a torch model to the constant `72114982` with this code

```
model = Net()
params = model.state_dict()

for k, v in params.items():
    params[k] = torch.full(v.shape, 72114982, dtype=torch.long) 

model.load_state_dict(params)
print(model.state_dict().values())
```

Then the print statement shows all values actually get set to `72114984` that is 2 off from the one I initially intended.

For simplicity define `Net` as follows

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(2, 2, 2)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(2, 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue of data types.

Model parameters are cast to float tensors. `72114984` is large enough that its float representation rounds to `72114984`.

You can verify this with the following:

```py
x = torch.tensor(72114982, dtype=torch.long)
y = x.float() # y will actually be `72114984.0`

# this returns `True` because x is cast to a float before evaluating
x == y
> tensor(True)

# for the same reason, this returns 0.
y - x
> tensor(0.)

# this returns `False` because the tensors have different values and we don't cast to float
x == y.long()
> tensor(False)

# as longs, the difference correctly evaluates to 2
y.long() - x
> tensor(2)
```